# Make iOS app invisible on app store for a few days

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iPhone app on app store. Due to some reasons, my server will not be available for a few days.

Is is possible to make my iOS app invisible on app for a few days and then make the same app available with a new update version?

Comment: Just remove it from sales and then put it back.

Comment: Thank you, If do it so, will it be a new app or just an updated version to existing app?

Comment: Same app, same version. You can just control whether the app is Ready for sale, Removed by developer (but still approved and can be put back anytime). Besides this one approved version, you can work on another one, i.e. Submit for approval.

Comment: Is it possible to de-select all territories so that it will not be available and later select them to make it available?

Answer (score 3):

**Remove app from sale in iTunes Connect**

1. Select your app
2. Click on Rights and Pricing
3. There is a link 'Unless you select specific stores, your app will be for sale in all App Stores worldwide.', click on the 'specific stores'
4. Deselect all locations
5. Save

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After a few days, can I select all those locations and save it to make the app available?

Comment: Yes sure, and it will be available in 30 - 60 minutes

Comment: can I provide another update to the same app if I de-select all the territories and set available date when update gets approved?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make sure that the new update replaced the old version of the app, in other words: you have to wait after your app approval for at least 1 hour to unhide your app.

Comment: I could find app availability date under Rights and Pricing section. Can I change it so that app will not be available till the specified date?

Comment: Sure, its the same, but when you deselect the territories you will get "Removed From Sale" for your app, the other way has the same results, but with no "Removed From Sale".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60006/discussion-between-satyanarayana-and-mutawe).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following tutorial given by apple and see the portion with the name

[Removing an App from Sale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)